# Can the FFI of LuaJIT be disabled, like the JIT?

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

For a project, I need to disable the FFI of LuaJIT for users of an API. I've been looking around LuaJIT's wiki and Stack Overflow and haven't found anything about this.

Comment: Compile LuaJIT with option `-DLUAJIT_DISABLE_FFI`

Comment: Or remove the ffi entry from globals, if you still want to use it, but disable it for your users. By globals I mean tables for loaded modules.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Why don't you put that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two ways to disable the FFI for scripts on LuaJIT:

1. [Compile it without FFI support:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22852273#comment34866001_22852273)
   Use option `-DLUAJIT_DISABLE_FFI`
2. [Remove FFI from the globals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22852273#comment34868207_22852273) and  filter `require`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could (or rather should, because if you don't trust your user, not only ffi is a problem, but also e.g. `setmetatable("",{...})`) use sandboxing. examples: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes, https://github.com/yEngine/YEng/blob/master/modules/sandbox/init.lua